# C# POST Request - Does Sending More Headers Make It Slower?

Tags: c#, post, get, httpwebrequest

So if I am making a POST request using the C# HttpWebRequest class, and I add heaps of headers, would it take longer to execute? I mean, if you think about it, wouldn't you be sending more data, thus taking longer?

For example:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.Headers["Header"] = "value";
request.Headers["AnotherOne"] = "Anothervalue";
request.Headers["Example"] = "valueAgain";
```

Would take longer than just adding one or two headers?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will take longer, but only at a macroscopic scale.  Any extra data is of course "more data", but a bunch of http headers are miniscule in the grand scheme of things.  I very much doubt you'd notice any difference between 5 and 30 headers.

Comment: But are we talking milliseconds, or nanoseconds?

Comment: @user2764359, profile it if it's important, but I really think you're worrying about something that is not worth worrying about.  It will be *unnoticeable*.  Of course, if you send 55,000 headers it may well be noticeable - but then you have other problems.

Comment: @user2764359 It's unlikely you ever should be sending enough headers to be concerned about it and if you are there are better optimizations to be concerned with such as cache/gzip etc.

Comment: @Slump How would I use gzip to improve the speed of my requests? Would that compress the response, or the actual request entity? Can you please link me to a tutorial/article about it?

Comment: @user2764359 it gzips the response from the server lessening usage of bandwidth... https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/gzip

Answer (score 2):

As others have said already, just adding more headers should not make much of a difference, as long as you dont add too many headers. If the extra headers are fitting inside a TCP packet, then as long as you stay within a TCP packet size, it should not make much of a difference as far as bytes on wire time is concerned.

However, the other thing to remember here is the semantics of the headers themselves. If the headers mean something to the server application, and if the application has to do more work to process the message, then yes, you will see a delay in the response.